# clojure java interop and interfaces

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am having trouble using a Java interface from Clojure.

I have the folowing class: public class OpenAccess

which has a method: static Connection connect(String url)

where Connection is a interface: public interface Connection

In Java I would do this to setup a connection:

```
Connection conn = OpenAccess.connect(url);
```

I tried the following from Clojure but it doesn't work:

```
(defn connection [url]
  (let [oa (access.OpenAccess.)
    connection (reify access.Connection
             .....
(.connect oa connection)))
```

it errors with "IllegalArgumentException No matching method found: connect for class access.OpenAccess"

I can't figure out how to properly execute Java interfaces from Clojure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a static call:

```
(defn connection [url]
  (OpenAccess/connect url))
```

And you would use it like this if you needed to type-hint it:

```
(let [^Connection conn (connection "http://foo")]
  // use your conn 
  )
```

You don't *need* the ^Connection but it will tell the compiler the type of the method invocations on conn which will avoid reflection.

Comment: It's generally better to type-hint the *names* in a let-binding, rather than the values, like `(let [^Connection conn (foo ...)] ...)`. Most of the time, as here, that doesn't matter, but in particular if `foo` is a macro, your typehint will be silently ignored, as discussed in http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-865.